# Good or best way to compile for "POSIX"?

Tags: posix

I tried to read the "[POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)" that is not very much. If I want to compile "POSIX compatible", is C99 even acceptable or do I have to use flags like `gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a POSIX compliant operating system, there is `c99`.

If you like to compile "POSIX compatible", you of course need a POSIX compatible operating system as non-POSIX platforms may have deviations that prevents you from being able to use a POSIX compliant source code.

Comment: This answer would be better if it linked to a source for the claim that all POSIX systems have a `c99` compiler. (And is it guaranteed to be in the path? And what flags does it support?)

Comment: Well, in theory a POSIX platform could be present without C language development environment, but this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: "in theory a POSIX platform could" **not** do the thing you said was required of all POSIX-compliant platforms?? If that's true, this answer is not only incomplete, it's just plain wrong! [Here's a doc page for `c99`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) that says in part: "On systems providing POSIX Conformance (see XBD Conformance), `c99` is required only with the C-Language Development option; XSI-conformant systems always provide `c99`. [...] The `c99` utility is based on the `c89` utility originally introduced in the ISO POSIX-2:1993 standard."